# How to embed JPanel into JavaFX pane?

Tags: java, swing, javafx, jpanel, pane

How can I add a `swingNode` to a `specific` pane?

I'm actually trying to add a `JPanel` that loads an *applet* to the transparent area of the following and I'm not sure how to do it.

[image]

Answer (score 20):

[`SwingNode`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/embed/swing/SwingNode.html) is a [javafx scene node](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Node.html) and can be added to any [javafx scene layouts](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/layout-tutorial/index.html).

To add a JPanel to a Pane and display it on JavaFX stage:

- Add JPanel to a SwingNode
- Assign the swingnode as a child to any of the layouts (which includes Pane).
- Set the layout as the root of the scene
- Set the scene to the stage and display it

A very simple code sample to show how you can add it to a Pane is (from `SwingNode` [Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/embed/swing/SwingNode.html)):

```
public class SwingNodeExample extends Application {

     @Override
     public void start(Stage stage) {
         final SwingNode swingNode = new SwingNode();
         createAndSetSwingContent(swingNode);

         Pane pane = new Pane();
         pane.getChildren().add(swingNode); // Adding swing node

         stage.setScene(new Scene(pane, 100, 50));
         stage.show();
     }

     private void createAndSetSwingContent(final SwingNode swingNode) {
         SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
             @Override
             public void run() {
                 JPanel panel = new JPanel();
                 panel.add(new JButton("Click me!"));
                 swingNode.setContent(panel);
             }
         });
     }

     public static void main(String[] args) {
         launch(args);
     }
 }
```

Comment: Thanks! would rep if I could!